# Can I use opencv 64 bit in visual studio 32 bit version in a 64 bit machine?

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013, x86, 64-bit

The question is just same as the topic. Can I use opencv 64 bit in visual studio 32 bit version in a 64 bit machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio is always a 32 bit application (at least so far), but you can compile your code into application that can run in 64 bit mode, and even run and debug the application in 64 bit mode from Visual Studio.

Comment: So as u say there is no problem with visual studio. Here is another issue. Can I use opencv x86 in my x64 machine?

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga: Yes, you can specify in the properties for the project that the platform target should be x86, then you can use 32 bit libraries with it.